# Spring boot unable to override value when original config with null value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The issue is that, when I am providing configuration from env variables, spring does not apply it to my existing config.

As in example

My config

```
config:
    property1: some value
```

and I want to add extra value to it by  adding them to the env variable as

```
config.property2 = some extra value
```

The same happens in integration tests when using

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"config.property2=some value"})
```

Spring does not read this value, (it's still null)

I am running it by

```
java -jar myapp.jar --config.property2=some value
```

Has anyone ever had a problem with it? Is it a bug, or just Spring does not allow this?

I've tried debugging code and was looking into documentation. Can't find anything.

Comment: `config.property` is generally not a proper environment variable. Use `CONFIG_PROPERTY2` instead.

Comment: Im a bit confused here. You've set config.property1 to a value and now you're expecting to override config.property1 by setting config.property2? Spring should save each of those as their own property that you would need to access under property1 and property2 respectively